# Upload to OneDrive with Offline Access

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, onedrive

I created a PCL project to interact with OneDrive using the REST API (upload/download/folder management, etc..).  The area that I am having a problem is ability to use OneDrive while the user is offline, everything else works.

When I redirect the user to start the OAUTH2 authentication, I use the following Url

```
string.Format("https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={0}&state={1}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={2}&scope=wl.basic wl.signin wl.offline_access wl.skydrive_update", _microsoftClientId, userId, Url.AbsoluteAction("CallBack", "Microsoft"))
```

I get the following error after the user logs in and authorizes the app.

```
There's a temporary problem

There's a temporary problem with the service. Please try again. If you continue to get this message, try again later.
```

If I change the scope to only include **wl.skydrive_update** it works, but I don't get a refresh_token.  I have tried different scopes, with different delimiters (%20, comma, space) I always get the error above after login and authorization.

I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Microsoft resolved the problem on their end.  Without any code changes, it is now working.

I now have a token, and a refresh token.

This is how I redirect to Microsoft Live

```
Response.RedirectPermanent(string.Format("https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={0}&state={1}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={2}&scope=wl.signin%20wl.skydrive_update%20wl.offline_access", _microsoftClientId, userId, Url.AbsoluteAction("CallBack", "Microsoft")));
```

My Callback Action

```
        public RedirectToRouteResult CallBack(string code, string state, string error, string error_description)
        {
            logger.Debug("Callback from Micrsoft");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error))
            {
                var client = new RestClient("https://login.live.com");
                var request = new RestRequest("oauth20_token.srf", Method.POST);
                request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
                request.AddParameter("code", code);
                request.AddParameter("client_id", _microsoftClientId);
                request.AddParameter("client_secret", _microsoftClientSecret);
                request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", Url.AbsoluteAction("CallBack", "Microsoft"));

                logger.Debug("POSTING to Micrsoft");
                var mslResponse = client.Execute<MicrosoftLiveResponse>(request);

                if (mslResponse != null && mslResponse.Data != null)
                {
                    logger.Debug("RESPONSE: " + mslResponse.Content);

                    var mslClient = mslResponse.Data;
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mslClient.error))
                    {

//Update the database and redirect to the Done Action
if (OauthBL.UpdateMicrosoftLiveToken(Utilities.ConvertToObjectId(state, ObjectId.Empty), mslClient.access_token, mslClient.refresh_token, mslClient.expires_in))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Done");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            logger.Debug("INITIAL ERROR:" + error + " - " + error_description);
            return RedirectToAction("Error");
        }
```

And My MicrosoftLiveResponse Entity

```
namespace Entities
{
    public class MicrosoftLiveResponse
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }

        public string authentication_token { get; set; }

        public string token_type { get; set; }

        public int expires_in { get; set; }

        public string refresh_token { get; set; }

        public string uid { get; set; }

        public string error { get; set; }

        public string error_description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Hope this is useful for someone